# Angular app with firebase auth and node.js / mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, firebase

I am just planning architecture for my web app and I just wanted to ask you, if it is good idea to use Firebase auth with Angular and mongoDB as a database. (I don't want to use Firestore realtime database)

Is a good idea to use queries directly from my Angular client or do I need some node.js/express backend for this? What would be the best solution?

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should be fine with simply making calls from Angular, but if I were you I would build a Node/Express server API that will perform CRUD operations against firebase Auth and MongoDB. Then in your Angular app, you simply make API calls to your internal server API.

This architecture will ensure some sort of scalability and integration. If you wish to build an iOS or Android app in the future to supplement your web app, you already have your NodeJS server ready to go. No need to rebuild a separate backend just for your mobile apps. I use this concept in all my projects: web or mobile.

Hope it helps.